# debugSymbolLevel SYMBOL_TABLE does not include symbols for native lib?

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, build.gradle

`Google Play` encourages you to include debug symbols when using native code. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#android_gradle_plugin_version_41_or_later) you can automatically include symbols when building an `.aab` bundle. However, neither AAB nor APK build seem to generate any symbols when `SYMBOL_TABLE` is specified.

**Shouldn't `debugSymbolLevel SYMBOL_TABLE` include symbols in the generated package?**

Changing this setting to `FULL` does seem to add the missing `.dbg` files in the `.aab\BUNDLE-METADATA\com.android.tools.build.debugsymbols` folder. Great, but what if the symbols become too large? The docs state:

> Note: There is a 300 MB limit for the native debug symbols file. If
> your debug symbols footprint is too large, use SYMBOL_TABLE instead of
> FULL to decrease the file size.

So how would you specify `SYMBOL_TABLE` and still get the generated symbols? Makes no sense.

### build.gradle

The relevant parts...

```
android {
    minSdkVersion 19
    ndkVersion "22.1.7171670"

    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

This [Google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197759808) seems related. Debug symbols are incorrectly stripped when performing a full rebuild.